# Cinema seat row c#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, webmethod

I've recently finished a small project that I have been working on, except there is a small problem that I'm trying to figure out.

This project utilizes C# web services using a SOAP client along with both the Request and Response Classes. This project has been designed to save inputted data. What it does is that it reserves a seat with a row in the cinema, and when I book that seat and try to select that seat again to find another available seat in the row (within the form), it displays them both as "0". However, when I book another seat in a different row, it successfully saves that data in the cache but it won't display any other seat and row within the "else if" statement of the code.

Here is the Webmethod for the Webservice

```
public string Name { get; set; } //gets and sets the Name from the ReserveSeatResponse
    public int Row { get; set; } //gets and sets the Row from the ReserveSeatResponse
    public int Seat { get; set; } //gets and sets the Seat from the ReserveSeatResponse

    private const int maxRows = 13; //sets the max amount of Rows in the Array tried setting the rows to 12, but since the array starts at 0, I had to set the Rows to 13)
    private const int maxSeats = 17; //sets the max amount of Seats in the Array (tried setting the seats at 16, but since the array starts at 0, I had to set it to 17)



    private bool[,]reservedSeats = new bool[13, 17]; //same description above, but this sets a boolean in the reserved seats, to check if its taken or no)
    private bool[,]reservedRows = new bool[13, 17]; //same description for the max row/seats.

    [WebMethod]
    public GetSeatResponse Booking (GetSeatRequest req)
    {

        GetSeatResponse resp = new GetSeatResponse();
      //  resp.Seat = req.SeatNumber;
      //  resp.Row = req.RowNumber;
        object abc = HttpContext.Current.Cache["CinemaReservation"];

        //if the cache does not exist
        if (abc == null)
        {
            //creates a blank multidimensional array
            reservedSeats = new bool[maxRows,maxSeats];

        }
        //if the cache exists
        else
        {
            //using the cache object as an array

            try
            {
                reservedSeats = (bool[,])abc;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        //if the seat is vacant
        if (reservedSeats[req.RowNumber, req.SeatNumber] != true)
        {
            resp.Name = req.Name;
            resp.Seat = req.SeatNumber;
            resp.Row = req.RowNumber;
            reservedSeats[req.RowNumber, req.SeatNumber] = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Cache["CinemaReservation"] = reservedSeats;
            return resp;
        }
        //if the seat is taken

        else if (reservedSeats[req.RowNumber, req.SeatNumber] != true)
        {
            bool breakTest = false;
            string Name = req.Name;
            int row = req.RowNumber;
            int seat = req.SeatNumber;
            for (int i = row; i < reservedSeats.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = seat; j < reservedSeats.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (reservedSeats[i, j] !=true )
                    {
                        resp.Name = Name;
                        resp.Row = i+1;
                        resp.Seat = j+1;
                        reservedSeats[i, j] = true;
                        breakTest = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                seat = 0;
                if (breakTest == true)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            //getNextSeat(req, resp, reservedSeats);
            HttpContext.Current.Cache["CinemaReservation"] = reservedSeats;


        }

        return resp;
```

And here is the part where I am stuck on in the method that calls from the Webservice

```
if (resp.erroresp != true)
            {
                if ((resp.Row > 0) && (resp.Seat > 0))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Hi there {0}!!, you have reserved a Seat at Row: {1} in Seat Number : {2}", resp.Name, resp.Row, resp.Seat));
                }

                else if (resp.erroresp != true)
                {
                    if ((resp.Row < 1) && (resp.Seat < 1))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Sorry, your selected Seat has been taken, however there is an available seat at row {0} in seat {1}", resp.Row, resp.Seat));
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: Why have you tagged cinema-4d for this ?

Comment: Looking at the last part of your code: With the `else if`, why do you repeat the criterion `resp.erroresp != true` that's already checked in the containing block? (If the type of `erroresp` is `bool`, you could write it `!resp.erroresp`.) You have a case for `Row` and `Seat` both greater than zero. Another case for **both** of them less than one. Do you really want a message like that if both are non-positive? What if one of them, say `Row`, is positive, and the other one, `Seat`, is not? Do you know that will never happen?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: I'm trying to find a unused row & or seat within the array itself and displaying it within the messagebox if that section in the array is taken, but I'm not too sure on how it is suppose to display the untaken/free X and Y axis section within the array if that (1,1   5,2 <etc.>) is already in use

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems with your code.

**Serverside:**

- `reservedRows` is never used. Whats its purpose?
- You define constants i.e. `maxRows` but you don't use them. Write

  ```
  private bool[,]reservedSeats = new bool[maxRows, maxSeats]
  ```
- In both checks (Seat taken or not) you use the same condition - that wont work. Just write:

  ```
  if (!reservedSeats[req.RowNumber, req.SeatNumber]) {
      // Seat is free
  } else {
      // Seat is taken
  }
  ```
- If you want to differentiate whether the returned seat is an alternative, you should include a boolean flag i your response or even better an enumeration like this:

  ```
  public enum ResultEnum {
    Ok,         // the requested seat is free
    Full,       // no seat is available
    Alternative // you got another seat
  }
  ```

**Clientside:**

- Your checks are somewhat redundant (you check two times for `resp.erroresp != true`) and not clear at all.
- When using the approach with an enum you can check like this:

  ```
  switch (resp.Result) {
     case ResultEnum.Ok:
       break;
     case ResultEnum.Full:
       break;
     case ResultEnum.Alternative:
       break;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I spot 2 errors in ur code!
Firstly, I couldn't see the initialization for your 2-dimensional array after:

```
`if (abc == null)
    {
        //creates a blank multidimensional array
        reservedSeats = new bool[maxRows,maxSeats];

    }`
```

Secondly, your if else conditions (reservedSeats[req.RowNumber, req.SeatNumber] != true) are exactly the same!

Hope this helps